# Reusing ActionResult code within Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, actionresult

If I have the following code **(EDIT: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I want to encapsulate the following (forget about the view its calling), so that I could do other stuff within the `ActionResult`)**:

```
public ActionResult ModelBased(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems) {
        var model = new ItemsViewModel();
        var selectedItems = new List<Item>();
        var postedItemIDs = new string[0];
        if (postedItems == null) postedItems = new PostedItems();

        if (items!= null && items.Any()) {
            postedCityIDs = items;
            postedItems.ItemIDs = items;
        }

        if (postedItems.ItemIDs != null && postedItems.ItemIDs.Any()) {
            postedItemIDs = postedIems.ItemIDs;
            model.WasPosted = true;
        }

        if (postedItemIDs.Any())
            selectedItems = ItemRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => postedItemIDs.Any(s => x.Id.ToString().Equals(s))).ToList();

        model.AvailableItems = ItemRepository.GetAll();
        model.SelectedItems = selectedItems;
        model.PostedItems = postedItems;

        return View(model);
    }
```

How might I reuse it in different Actions in my controller without having to copy/paste. I tried doing a private method with the code. But I am stuck on:

1. Either calling it wrong within an action method : `private void Item (Item item) {//copied code from above}` then calling `Item(item);` in the action; or
2. It has something to do with the `(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems)` that I am doing wrong; or
3. Something entirely different that I am not doing right.

Any examples would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** The code above works with a CheckBoxList. It's one particular CheckBoxList. But I want to be able to use it in other views without having to copy/paste the code to other `ActionResults`. Just calling the `ActionResult` won't work, because I plan on doing other things. In particular, I have code for wizards in each `ActionResult`, such as:

```
if ((nextButton != null) && ModelState.IsValid)
     return RedirectToAction("EMailConfirm");
return View("EMail/BasicDetails", myData);
```

which are returning specific views, so call to just the `ActionResult` won't work, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return View(model);` tries to find a view for the original action.

Specify `return View("ModelBased", model);` to always render the view named `"ModelBased"`

---

```
public void SomeAction(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems)
{
    // Modify the data as your like
    return ModelBased(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems);
}

public void SomeOtherAction(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems)
{
    // Modify the data as your like
    return ModelBased(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems);
}

private ActionResult ModelBased(string[] items, PostedItems postedItems) {
    var model = new ItemsViewModel();
    var selectedItems = new List<Item>();
    var postedItemIDs = new string[0];
    if (postedItems == null) postedItems = new PostedItems();

    if (items!= null && items.Any()) {
        postedCityIDs = items;
        postedItems.ItemIDs = items;
    }

    if (postedItems.ItemIDs != null && postedItems.ItemIDs.Any()) {
        postedItemIDs = postedIems.ItemIDs;
        model.WasPosted = true;
    }

    if (postedItemIDs.Any())
        selectedItems = ItemRepository.GetAll()
            .Where(x => postedItemIDs.Any(s => x.Id.ToString().Equals(s))).ToList();

    model.AvailableItems = ItemRepository.GetAll();
    model.SelectedItems = selectedItems;
    model.PostedItems = postedItems;

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: That's the orignal `ActionResult`. I am trying to figure out a way to reuse that code in other actions in the controller. Basically, to reuse that code because I need to place it in other actions. I would rather keep it DRY.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Put the code in the private method. But you need to specify the view name to get it working.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. I see what you are saying. My problem would be if I add code for a wizard and redirects or returning specific views. See my edit above.

Comment: how to use an actionresult of another controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is unclear, however, I would normally move common functionality into a seperate method and mark it with [NonAction] attribute. E.g.

```
[NonAction]
protected UserInfo GetUserInfo(string username)
{
   // Return relevant data
}
```

I would then call GetUserInfo in your action method.

**Edit:**

You need to look into partial views. You can think of a partial view as a control that you can re-use on multiple pages. For example, I can put a login control in a partial view and renged it on multiple pages. This will promote code re-usability.

I can't give you the example as I haven't done this for a while, but you'd have to do the following:

1. Instead of  `return View();` you'll have to `return PartialView("_NameOfYourPartialView", viewModel);`
2. Modify your view, so it's no longer a view, but a partial view.

You'll need to do a bit of reading and try it out for yourself.

Good luck

Comment: You are on the right track. I want to take out the common functionality in the `ActionResult` above. I tried `private void` but can't figure out how to call it in the action.

Comment: Hi, can you please write in words what your action method should do. I'm unclear with what ModelBased means. I normally associate action method with a user action.

Comment: `ModelBased` is just returning the view `ModelBased.cshtml`, which has a CheckBoxList. I want to reuse the CheckBoxList in other views (via an `ActionMethod`), but don't want to have to copy/paste the code in each one, but rather have a private method and call it.

Comment: Partial views would be great...for a view. I am trying to encapsulate the `ActionResult` code for reuse in the controller. But there's an idea, a "Partial Controller". That would be &trade; and/or &copy;.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this action from another action that returns `ActionResult`.

```
public ActionResult OtherAction()
{
    return ModelBased(items, postedItems);
}
```

Also, why `private void`? Which part do you actually want to reuse? If it takes an `Item` and returns `ItemsViewModel`, it should be `private ItemsViewModel` - depends on the part you want to reuse. `void` doesn't return anything.